# Why is echo -e behaving weird in a Makefile?

Tags: echo, gnu-make

I was writing a Makefile (on Ubuntu 20.04, if it's relevant) and noticed some interesting behavior with `echo`. Take this simple Makefile:

```
test.txt:
        @echo -e 'hello\nworld'
        @echo -e 'hello\nworld' > test.txt
```

When I run `make`, I would expect to see the same thing on stdout as in test.txt, but in fact I do not. I get this on stdout:

```
hello
world
```

but this in test.txt:

```
-e hello
world
```

Meanwhile, if I remove `-e` from both lines in the Makefile, I get this on stdout:

```
hello\nworld
```

and this in test.txt:

```
hello
world
```

This had me wondering if `echo` detects the redirection and behaves differently, but it doesn't when I just run it manually in the shell with `/bin/echo -e 'hello\nworld' > test.txt` (which yields `hello` and `world` on separate lines, as I would normally expect). I even went so far as to confirm that the Makefile is using /bin/echo instead of a shell builtin by adding an `@echo --version` line.

What is going on here?

Comment: Related: [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

UNIX compliant implementations of `echo` are required to output `-e<space>hello<newline>world<newline>` there.

Those that don't are not compliant. Many aren't which means it's almost impossible to use `echo` portably, [`printf` should be used instead](/q/65803). `bash`'s `echo`, in some (most) builds of it, is only compliant when you enable both the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options. That might be the `echo` behaviour you were expecting.

Same for the `echo` standalone utility that comes with GNU `coreutils` which is only compliant if it's invoked with `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` set in its environment (and is of a recent enough version).

`make` normally runs `sh` to interpret the command lines on each action line.

However, the GNU implementation of `make`, as an optimisation, can run commands directly if the code is simple enough and it thinks it doesn't need to invoke a shell to interpret it.

That explains why `echo --version` gives you `/bin/echo`, but `echo ... > file` needs a shell to perform the redirection.

You can use `strace -fe execve make` to see what `make` executes (or the `truss`/`tusc`... equivalent on your system if not Linux).

Here, it seems that while your `/bin/echo` is not compliant, your `sh` has a `echo` builtin that is compliant.

Here, use `printf` if you want to expand `echo`-style escape sequences:

```
printf '%b\n' 'hello\nworld'
```

In its *format* argument, `printf` understands C-style escape sequences (there's a difference with the echo-style ones for the `\0xxx` (echo) vs `\xxx` (C) octal sequences)

```
printf 'hello\nworld\n'
```

Here, you could also do:

```
printf '%s\n' hello world
```

Which is the common and portable way to output several arguments on separate lines.

Another approach would be to add:

```
SHELL = bash
```

To your `Makefile` for `make` to invoke `bash` (assuming it's installed and found in `$PATH`) instead of `sh` to interpret the command lines. Or invoke `make` as `make <target> SHELL=bash`.

That won't necessarily make it more portable as while there are more and more systems where `bash` is installed by default these days, there are some (like on Solaris) where `bash` is built so that its `echo` builtin behaves the standard way by default.

Setting `SHELL` to anything other than `/bin/sh` also has the side effect of disabling GNU `make`'s optimisation mentioned above, so with `make <target> SHELL=sh` or `make <target> SHELL=/bin//sh`, you'd get consistent behaviours between the two invocation, while still not having to add a dependency to bash.

Comment: I assume you meant "POSIX-compliant" not "UNIX-compliant" in the first sentence

Comment: @Esther, POSIX merged with the Single UNIX Specification (formerly X/Open Portability Guide) in SUSv3/POSIX2001, with the difference between the two identified with options (mostly XSI: X/Open System Interface). Here, what I call UNIX is POSIX+XSI. With POSIX alone, the behaviour of that `echo -e '...\...'` is unspecified because of the backslash.